# Insert multiple rows using single insert statement

Tags: sql, insert

I am trying to insert into table variable using following query.
   but its throwing an error.
   Please help on inserting multiple selects using single insert statement.

```
      DECLARE @AddressRecordsToPurge TABLE  
    (  
      RowID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),  
        GUIDValue Nvarchar(max) ,  
     GuidColumn Nvarchar(max) ,  
      GuidTable Nvarchar(max)  
     )    

    Insert Into @AddressRecordsToPurge values ( (Select            
    EMPLOYMENTSEQUENCENUMBER FROM ACCOUNTANTSREFERENCE  WHERE  
    CustomerNumber =  @CustomerNumber AND Customerversionnumber =  
    @CustomerVersionNumber AND EMPLOYMENTSEQUENCENUMBER IS NOT 
     NULL), 'EMPLOYMENTSEQUENC ENUMBER', 'ACCOUNTANTSREFERENCE');
```

My select statement returns multiple values and I want to have it this way only. Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly off:

```
Insert Into @AddressRecordsToPurge (GuidValue, GuidColumn, GuidTable)
SELECT EMPLOYMENTSEQUENCENUMBER, 'EMPLOYMENTSEQUENCENUMBER', 'ACCOUNTANTSREFERENCE'
FROM ACCOUNTANTSREFERENCE
WHERE CustomerNumber =  @CustomerNumber
    AND Customerversionnumber = @CustomerVersionNumber
    AND EMPLOYMENTSEQUENCENUMBER IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: You are legend brother. It worked as smooth as cheesecake..cheers